# Python - Sending Data to a .NET Web Service with Authentication

Tags: python, linux, web-services, python-2.7, asterisk

I am working on trying to send XML data to a .NET web service, from an Asterisk Linux box, using Python.

The problems I am running into are:

> -- if I use HTTPlib, I can send the XML data; but, the not authenticate first.
>
> -- if I use HTTPlib2, I can authenticate; but, I can't get it to send the data.

In the end, I just need to periodically send data to a client's web service.  On my end, I'm not concerned with the response, just sending the data.

Any thoughts on this?  Maybe I'm pursuing the wrong path using HTTPlib?  Thanks for any assistance at all.  I'm not opposed to using a different language; Python just seemed the simplest when this project started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very popular module for this is

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

works great for me for all sorts of requests with and without authentication.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying that out now...  I'll post back if it works.